# mouse cursor moving to the left ubuntu 19.10 lenovo t460s

Tags: kernel

have bought lenovo t460s(previously it had windows 10 working perfectly) after installing ubuntu 19.10 my mouse cursor is moving to the left after 2 mins and the touch pad sensitivity is compromised it's very annoying please help!!!!

Comment: Common issue with ThinkPads. Trying to recall solution.

Comment: have noticed it through my research i don't know why

Comment: When using 18.04 LTS, does not appear.